# gdata AttributeError: 'ContactEntry' object has no attribute 'name'

Tags: python, gdata, gdata-api, google-shared-contacts, google-profiles-api

Using GData Python libraries, version 2.0.18

Attempting to retrieve contact list using the Service approach (not Client like the sample app).  It appears that the return is mapped to a ContactEntry (good), but it gives error when I try to access the name attribute:

AttributeError: 'ContactEntry' object has no attribute 'name'

```
from gdata.contacts.service import ContactsService
(...)
        self.client = ContactsService(source='appname', additional_headers=additional_headers )
        feed = self.client.GetContactsFeed(uri=query.ToUri())
```

self.client is a gdata.contacts.service

GetContactsFeed uses

```
def GetContactsFeed(self, uri=None):
    uri = uri or self.GetFeedUri()
    return self.Get(uri, converter=gdata.contacts.ContactsFeedFromString)
```

The sample code uses `desired_class=gdata.contacts.data.ContactsFeed`

Seems like there should be a name attribute.
Is my syntax wrong?

Comment: Please, provide [Short, Self Contained, Correct, Example](http://www.sscce.org/) and full traceback.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is the issue for the python contacts sample vs my implementation:
in gdata/sample/contacts/contacts_example.py it uses gdata.contacts.Client which (long chain to it) calls for the atom classes to use `desired_class=gdata.contacts.data.ContactsFeed`.
The service, as pointed out in the question, uses `converter=gdata.contacts.ContactsFeedFromString`.
This converter comes from the init file, src/gdata/contacts/**init**.py, as do the class definitions.  Obviously at this point, you know what's coming -- the classes for the xml in the initializer do not match the ones in the data file.
I added these missing, incorrect ones in to initializer and things worked as expected.  Alternatively, changing to use desired_class would do it too (at some point you'd have to map to converter...isn't supported directly in service.py), or adding converter to data.ContactsFeed, etc.

Hope this helps someone.